# Sqlalchemy array_length function

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Does SQLALCHEMY has a function to be used in queries for array_length?

ie:

```
ssn.query(models.MedicationLog.dose_date,
                         func.array_length(models.MedicationLog.
                                    dose_taken_times).label('dose_taken_times'))
```

Comment: Do you mean length or [`array_agg`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.array_agg)? Here is a [SO Post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23262484/2549021) about how to use this.

Comment: Length. Since the count will not give length of the array. But let me check the aggregate. Thanks @AKS

Comment: [`array_length`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) takes two arguments `array_length(array, dimension)`

Comment: @AKS Thanks. It works, only change I had to do was use max aggregate function as I dont have the dose_taken_times in the group by.

Comment: Please add the changes you made in the answer and accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it with using max and array_length

```
data = ssn.query(models.MedicationLog.dose_date,
                         func.sum(func.array_length(
                             models.MedicationLog.dose_taken_times, ARRAY_DEPTH
                         )).label('dose_taken_times')).order_by(models.MedicationLog.dose_date).\
        group_by(models.MedicationLog.dose_date).all()
```